# Hard disk resurrection

Tags: hard-drive

So I had this very old (Seagate Barracuda 3.5") hard disk stashed away because it stopped working (approximately 8 years ago). At the time (8 years ago or something) I took it to a repair shop but they said nothing could be done. And indeed the drive, either through an external case or plugged in on the motherboard was not working (windows and linux), it kept making this sound like it wanted to start spinning but it stopped, then again trying to spin again then stopping again ("buzz" for 2 seconds,silence for 2-3 seconds,"buzz" for 2 seconds...).

So, today I got a new adaptor (sata 3.5" to usb 2.0) for unrelated stuff and just tried this disk with it and it worked (in an old laptop with ubuntu 16). I could even copy stuff away from it, delete stuff. Worked perfectly, the files were intact. But then, after 30-40 minutes approximately, it once again stopped working and it started making those sounds I described above. I don't know if it was random, but at the time I tried to open an image and it stopped working (maybe this one image was corrupted and it caused it to stop? All other images/videos opened fine).

So I guess my question is, how do I get it working again. I tried tapping it, to unstuck it but I don't want to hit it too hard. I had given up on it but it would seem that it's not completely dead. It seems to me like it has a "minor" mechanical problem, like it gets stuck somewhere (randomly) and once stuck it's difficult for it to start spin again.

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? a) Extract the data or b) attempt to put this back into normal use? a) may be possible, b) just give up now & throw it away [smash it if it may contain sensitive data]

Comment: I just want the files. If I could get it to operate again it would be great but I don't think I will ever trust it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got sensitive information you need to recover on it, I'd suggest a repair business with a clean room environment, because this would be the only way to "open it up and see what's stuck (mechanically) inside".

Those services are sort of expensive (usually $100+/workhour in a clean room, plus additional costs of e.g. donor parts or for more difficult problems (disk encryption etc.)). Keep in mind, that they usually WON'T CHARGE anything if they can't recover your data, but since this seems to be a mechanical fault, maybe inside the drive motor or HSA (head stack assembly) motor, I am quite confident that a mechanic could fix it.

The behaviour you observed is not uncommon - due to changing environmental factors (mainly temperature), devices you thought were dead will "magically" work again. But as a hard drive contains spinning parts, generating vibrational forces, a possible loose connection could get torn apart again after a few minutes running.

If you want further reading on hard drive recovery, you can read on this company's site:
[harddriverecovery.org](https://www.harddriverecovery.org/pricing.html)

Comment: I mean, I want the files, but they're not worth 100$/hour. I guess there's not much to do other that check once in a while and hope to be lucky

Comment: I've seen a lot of videos where people open up drives for a decent amount of time without a clean room. Repair the drive and get it working long enough to extract the data out of it. You might want to check that out on youtube.

Comment: @Sickest depends on the Ariel density of the drive platters how lucky you get doing it outside a clean room. Risky business.